# format label caption with accounting format

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get a label to format the same as a cell with the accounting format applied.

I've tried:

```
label.Caption = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(ws.Cells(3, 59), "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)")
```

And

```
label.Caption = Format(ws.Cells(3, 59), "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
```

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pretty close

```
Dim something as String
something = ws.Cells(3,59).Value
something = Format(something,"_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)")
label.Caption = something
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: I tried this but the formatting came out as the Currency format and not to accounting format.

Comment: Edited to reflect. Thanks @pnuts

Comment: Still does't work properly but i used this format to get is close. here was my final solution. label.Caption = Format(wsName.Cells(3, 59), "$ #,##0.00;$ (#,##0.00);$ ""-"";_(@_)")